# Resize image based on table size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a table on top of an image but I am having issues. The table's content is dynamic and I need to be able to make the height of this image fit the size of the table.

Here is what it looks like: 
[image: My HTML page]

Here is my code:

```
<div style="position:relative;margin-top:20px;">
<img style="position:relative; max-height:100%;max-width:100%" src="~/Content/Images/menu13.jpg">
@using (Html.BeginForm("order", "menu", "post"))
{

    <table style="position:absolute;top:102px;left:110px;color:white;  font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:16px;" class="">

        <tr>

            <th style="width:150px;">Day</th>
            <th style="width:150px;">Meal</th>
            <th class="text-center">Normal</th>
            <th style="width:100px;"></th>
            <th class="text-center">No carb</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th style="width:240px;" class="text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Kiddies
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Standard
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Large
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>

            <th></th>

            <th style="width:240px;" class="text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Kiddies
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Standard
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Large
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        @{


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)//foreach day in the week
    {

        string size = "";
        string type = "";
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;">@Model.Menu[i].Day</td>

            <td>
                <b>@Model.Menu[i].NormalMeal</b>
                <br />
                <p>@Model.Menu[i].Description</p>
                <p><b>@Model.Menu[i].LowMeal</b></p>
            </td>

            @for (int p = 0; p < 2; p++) //for normal and nocarb
            {
                if (p == 0)
                {
                    type = "normal";
                }
                else
                {
                    type = "nocarb";
                }
                if (p == 1)
                {
                    <td></td>
                }
                <td class="text-center">

                    <div class="row">
                        @for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) //the sizes
                        {
                            if (j == 0)
                            {
                                size = "kid";
                            }
                            else if (j == 1)
                            {
                                size = "standard";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                size = "large";
                            }
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select style="position:relative;top:0px; font-size:12px;" name="@(Model.Menu[i].Day.ToLower().ToString() + "_"+type+"_" + size)" @if(i<=disabledDays){ @disabled}>
                                    <option> </option>
                                    @for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
                                    {
                                        <option>@k</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        }

                    </div>
                </td>
            }


        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <hr />
                </td>
            </tr>
    }
        }

    </table>

}
```

Comment: hi dude i think you can make them by separating in different wrappers (div) and then apply the css accordingly with your use this will make easy and if you provide the jsfiddle then i will try to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to break that into three images, like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then, use the top and bottom as non-repeating backgrounds on your `<thead>` and `<tfoot>`, with the middle slice as a repeat-y background on your `<tbody>`.

Depending on your browser compatibility requirements, you could also stack all three backgrounds on a single element (e.g. the top level `<table>` element): http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds